# fastest way to connect node.js process with java/scala code

Tags: java, node.js, performance, ipc, shared-memory

I have a computation library implemented with java/scala. And I also have a little of node.js code serving my application. I need to find a way how to connect this 2 worlds with maximum performance, but also simplicity in mind. I was thinking about inter process communication via shared memory, but don't find any mature way to do that in node.js

This should work mostly as a proxy mechanism to call some java (ideally any) code from node.js code. From node.js to java side it will be only request metadata passing, however from java to node.js sometime it could be significant data returned (let's say 100-200 kb as upper border, and around 600-1000 bytes in 90% of the cases) However amount of that's request could be significant.

Think OpenMP could be an option, but also can't find any openmp protocol implementation for Node. However there is also no clear project for java as well.

---

Looks like for the current moment there is several alternatives:

1. Native extension + Java Unsafe (currently extracted via reflection, should be opened in JDK 9) and using shared memory in C/C++ based env (need investigation and development. Looses for Node -> c -> Java could be higher than shared memory benefits)
2. Use socket (quite fast on linux, not sure about Windows, crossplatform)
3. FastCGI (still use sockets transfering inside, so will be slower than 1 option)
4. ZeroMQ/Nanomessage as transport layer (again socket inside, but simplified development)
5. @David's answer. However can't say anything specific about it. Investigation needed.

Comment: Since you mention shared memory, do you have huge data amounts to transfer between processes? What performance do you require that standard mechanisms like sockets don't work for you?

Comment: It will be mostly a proxy mechanism to call some java code from node.js code. From node.js to java side it will be only request metadata passing, however from java to node.js sometime it could be significant data returned (let's say 100-200 kb as upper border, and around 600-1000 bytes in 90% of the cases) However amount of that's request could be significant.

Comment: Would something like node-cgi (which complies with RFC3575) be an acceptable solution given your performance requirements ?

Comment: I think http infrastructure is too heavy and will be slower than socket connection or message passing.

Comment: There is no HTTP involved between node and the underlying (Java?) component in CGI. It is based on spawning another process in node which will ultimately execute your Java component, which will itself respond to an initial request. node-cgi basically acts as a router between your process standard output and the client (using pipes).

Comment: Also note that pipes are one of the fastest IPC mechanism on UNIX systems in terms of throughput (http://cybertiggyr.com/throughput/throughput.html).

Comment: Thanks, I've read a bit about CGI. It's not an option because I don't expect  stdin/stdout is fast thing, and also I'm afraid about additional pitfals connected with up and run scripts, etc. FastCGi looks like a better alternative, however inside it's still use sockets, so using plain soket without fastcgi at all will be just faster and more clear.

Comment: Not sure. You could have a look at ZeroMQ.

Comment: @hgoebl I'm pretty well familiar with zmq. It's allow to do things via shared memory, but I not sure it will work in cross language env. I think in this case it will be use socket mechanism  for transferring data and in that case plain socket still will be faster than sockets covered via zmq (if decently written of course). However still investigation needed.

Comment: Re FastCGI, JVM startup times and memory footprint are (probably) (still) too big to consider it.  Maybe after JDK9 :-).  So a single JVM which established a pipe or unix domain socket with some simple protocol to multiplex multiple requests to multiple results, would probably be faster and less bother.

Comment: Re ZeroMQ, the [Node.js binding](http://zeromq.org/bindings:node-js) seems only to offer sockets.  That it only does so would tend to back up the idea that Node.js has no 'mature' facility for shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if sockets are too slow for you, why not keep it *in-process*?

You could try:

1. running your unmodified Node.js scripts on [Nodyn](http://nodyn.io/) which in turn runs on [DynJS](http://dynjs.org/) *on the JVM*; *-or-*
2. if you've not particular to the Node.js stack, but like the idea of extreme-wait-free throughput on the JVM, code it all up in [vert.x](http://vertx.io/).

**Note**: An alternative to Nodyn/DynJS *would have been* the [Avatar.js](https://avatar-js.java.net/index.html) project, which uses [Nashorn](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nashorn/), which in turn is shipped with recent JVM's and uses the latest and greatest bytecode operators.  However in late 2015 the Avatar.js project feels abandoned. :-\

Comment: Thanks for proposal. It's looks like there is no any more or less defined way to do so, so in any case decent research will be needed. I have a plan to try different options with benchmark when will have a time.